# Asp.net UserControl with Templates is not working inside user controls

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have created a real simple templated UserControl and

I can now add this control to my Asp.net WebApplication using:

```
<components:Box BoxType="Help" Title="Content Title" runat="server">
    <Content>
        <asp:TextBox runat="Server" ID="txtName"/>
        This is my awesome content!<br />
        <b>Test</b>
    </Content>
</components:Box>
```

i can embed this in a page (aspx) but i is not working in usercontrol (ascx). when i use this inside usercontrol, the designer file (.ascx.designer.cs) itself not getting generated.

getting the following error:

Element 'Box' is not a known element. This can occur if there is an error in the webpage, or 
 the web.config file is missing.

Update: sometimes it works! i created couple of controls. it works in some place and it doesnot works in someother place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[How To Access One UserControl from Another Using ASP.NET](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=155)

Comment: the question is little different. i want to use one user control (A) in another one (B). with out any templated control in (A) it works fine. but if any templated controls defined in (A) then it is not working. this is specific to Asp.Net Web Application PRoject. it works well in Asp.net WEbSite.

Comment: @Mahes: hmmm, then I am not sure. I will have to look further in to this.